# Category url generate 404 error

Tags: categories, permalinks, 404-error

My permalink setting is: `/blog/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/`
everything is working fine except the category URL.

for example, my website generate category URL like -

**www.example.com/blog/`article`/**

And I can't visit this page got 404 not found

**article** is a category
but my other website generate  like
**www.example.com/blog/category/`article`/**

How to fix this issue. I'm new to WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem. 
Yoast SEO Plugins
Advance Change URLs

Strip the category base (usually /category/) from the category URL.
After switching it to keep 
all working as aspected.

Comment: I can't tell you how many sites I have seen messed up from Yoast, esp. Yoast Premium which changes URLs in the database.